# iOS App Store Unique App Names?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Must iOS apps have a globally unique name?  The [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) implies that they do, but doesn't say so directly.  The closest it comes is (p71):

> As a result of this deletion [after not delivering a binary within 120 days], your app
>   name will be able to be used by
>   another developer

If an app is renamed, does the old name then become available again?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Apps do indeed have to have unique names. If a desired name isn't available, developers commonly solve the problem by adding a bit of description to the name, making it unique, e.g. "SuperText - Text Editor for Geeks" when "SuperText" isn't available.

Until recently there was a significant name-squatting problem, with devs creating placeholder apps that tied up names indefinitely. Apple cleared all of those out last Fall, making a large number of names available again. Now an app created in iTunes Connect but not submitted for review will receive a warning after 150 days and if there's still no submission 30 days later, the placeholder is deleted and the name is freed up to other developers (as per the policy you quote). Significantly, that specific name is *no longer available to the developer that first used it,* so be certain you're going to submit soon after creating the app in ITC.

As to approved and then later renamed apps, I don't know what Apple's policy is, and it's not spelled out anywhere that I've ever seen. I think it's somewhat unlikely that the old name becomes available due to potential consumer confusion, though: "I bought 'Buddy's Checkers' but now it's saying that I didn't buy it."

**Note: Updated from 90 days to 150 days, per Apple's change. See "App Name Expiry" in the *[iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW20).*** *(thanks to Alexander)*

Comment: First time I mention this on a post, but it has to be done: very clear and well written response addressing all aspects of the question - excellent. Thanks

Comment: App Name reservations no longer expire. I learned this by reaching out to Apple directly and reading [this blog post](http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/).

Answer (score 3):

As an aside note: Apple has recently extended its 120 day limit to 180 days. It means that if you don't upload a binary within the 180-day period, your app is deleted from iTunes Connect. As a result, you cannot reuse the app name, SKU or bundle ID. See more details in the App Name Expiry section of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1,)